# Embedding one SVN working copy in another

Tags: svn

How can I have my working copy for my project (in my own SVN instance) contain another from an open source project that uses SVN as well? I would like to keep the open source project up to date from its source while keeping it in my instance. I'm using VisualSVN and TortoiseSVN on Windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subversion merging changes from a different repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471618/subversion-merging-changes-from-a-different-repository)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I agree with Oli's answer that using vendor branches is generally preferred, I believe a direct answer to your question is to use [Externals Definitions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externals).

Comment: +1: I had never seen that before in the manual.  Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think SVN supports cross-repository linking.

But generally speaking, you shouldn't be doing this.  You probably don't want to always be using the bleeding-edge of the 3rd-party repository, as it could have bugs.  Usually, you want to pick and choose stable release points to import.  The suggested mechanism is [*vendor branches*](http://durak.org/sean/pubs/software/version-control-with-subversion-1.6/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot embed another svn repository into yours, but you can maintain a link to it using externals. External is a core functionality, and works with all clients. To use externals, set the `svn:externals` property to:

```
dirname    http://domain.com/url-to-project/tag/v1.0
```

The second project will appear in directory `dirname`. This project will be updated together with your project.

When including another project which is not ruled by you, it is wise to point the externals to a stable tag.