# Tortoise SVN can't sync two branches. Why?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository, branch

I've been using TortoiseSVN for a good while now and we have come to like it quite much. But I was asked to use another repository as well and sync rep1's single branch with rep2. Yet when I write to branch tag as a first test it says:

```
Error: Source and dest appear not to be in the same repository (src:   ...
dst..)
```

I was a little surprised. So what if they are in different repositories? Is there no way to sync a single branch in 2 repositories aside from complete branch import?

Comment: Given that *sync* is not a Subversion term, I think you should explain what you want to accomplish. Furthermore, you paste a very concrete error message: it must come from a specific command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subversion merging changes from a different repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471618/subversion-merging-changes-from-a-different-repository)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check out the branch from repository 1 and then merge changes from the branch in repository 2 here. Have a look at this related question: [Subversion merging changes from a different repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471618/subversion-merging-changes-from-a-different-repository)

Answer (score 0):

Svn does not allow you to merge change sets between two repositories. By importing your working folder to another repository, you will lose your history.

The better idea is to use "svnadmin dump" and "svnadmin load" commands. They will preserve your history. But be aware of the commit numbers, because they will not be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what i hoped that tortoise svn could have done was that i could use SVNBridge to update local rep from rep1(std SVN) and update a single branch in rep2(Bridged to TFS) from the local rep. It seems tortoise svn cannot do so.

what i did was, first grab everything(branches, tags, etc) and create a local image of rep1. Then i opened the project from eclipse and imported the project in my local rep (updated from rep1). I disconnected the project from team menu. Then clicked Share Project and pointed to my TFS server. The eclipse version was now connected directly to TFS. Everytime people commit something to the regular SVN (rep1) i would update the local rep then in eclipse in team menu, click detect local changes and check in those changes to the TFS. This was i have some semblance of history in TFS as well as full history in SVN.

If you guys have a more sensible solution please do share:)

Thanks,