# SVN - Can you have two different servers for one one working copy

Tags: svn

I have access to some source code via a license agreement.  So they have given me read access to the SVN server.

I can make any modifications I like to this source code and this works fine.  I update perodically and resolve any conflicts as they may occur.

The problem I have is that my personal changes are not backed up anywhere as my SVN access is read-only I can't check them in.

Is there a way in which I could check these in somehow...i.e. perhaps have another server location to check them into (my own) and that way I've got a backup.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subversion merging changes from a different repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471618/subversion-merging-changes-from-a-different-repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to use `svnsync` to [mirror their repository onto another copy of it on a server you control](http://www.cardinalpath.com/how-to-use-svnsync-to-create-a-mirror-backup-of-your-subversion-repository/).  You'd then checkout from your (mirror) server and commit/update as usual.  The only caveat is that your mirror server needs to be synced with the original before you can commit.

Since the group is probably very unlikely to add a post-commit hook to their repository to update your mirror, you'll have to do it manually.  It just means you'd need to run `svnsync`, then `svn update`, then `svn commit` in one go.